# Javascript file Loading in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I am doing some work in django.
In my `BaseTemplate.html` I have added a js file like this

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/Jquery/Local/Base.js"></script>
</head>
```

And I have made another file name `CreateABC.html` and I have a js file for this page which I loaded in the body of it.

```
{%block content%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/Jquery/Local/CreateABC.js"></script>
{%endblock %}
```

In the CreateABC page the `CreateABC.js` file is loading before `Base.js` file. but I have some functions in `Base.js` file which have to be executed before the loading of `CreateABC.js` file.
I guess the `Base.js` should load before the `CreateABC.js` as it is in the `BaseTeamplate.html`,
right? Any solutions?

Comment: did you add `{% extends "BaseTemplate.html" %}` in `CreateABC.html` file? just look at the source code of the result and watch what is happening. Then give us more details

Comment: Yes I used `{%extends "BaseTemplate.html" %}`